# Bin-packing-problem - is there a way to do it better?

Tags: javascript

I have finished our first version of bin-packing-problem script, but would like to ask you, if there's a better way to organize boxes?
Boxes should be organized to save as much space as possible, to make the "main" (blue) box as small as possible.

But in some cases boxes do not organize well.

```js
let GrowingPacker = function() { };

GrowingPacker.prototype = {

  fit: function(blocks) {
    var n, node, block, len = blocks.length;
    var w = len > 0 ? blocks[0].w : setFloat(0);
    var h = len > 0 ? blocks[0].h : setFloat(0);
    this.root = { x: setFloat(0), y: setFloat(0), w: w, h: h };
    for (n = 0; n < len ; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h)) {
        block.fit = this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h);
      }
      else {
        block.fit = this.growNode(block.w, block.h);
      }
    }
  },

  findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
      return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    else if ((w.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.w)) && (h.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.h)))
      return root;
    else
      return null;
  },

  splitNode: function(node, w, h) {
    node.used = true;
    node.down  = { x: node.x,                 y: Decimal.add(node.y, h), w: node.w,                 h: Decimal.sub(node.h, h) };
    node.right = { x: Decimal.add(node.x, w), y: node.y,                 w: Decimal.sub(node.w, w), h: h                      };
    return node;
  },

  growNode: function(w, h) {
    var maxWidth = setFloat(limit.area.max.width + limit.milling - (limit.area.border + form.option.panelization[1].padding) * 2);
    var maxHeight = setFloat(limit.area.max.height + limit.milling - (limit.area.border + form.option.panelization[1].padding) * 2);
    
    var possibleGrowDown = Decimal.add(this.root.h, h).lessThanOrEqualTo(maxHeight);
    var possibleGrowRight = Decimal.add(this.root.w, w).lessThanOrEqualTo(maxWidth);
    
    var canGrowDown  = possibleGrowDown && w.lessThanOrEqualTo(this.root.w);
    var canGrowRight = possibleGrowRight && h.lessThanOrEqualTo(this.root.h);
    
    var shouldGrowDown  = canGrowDown  && Decimal.add(this.root.h, h).lessThanOrEqualTo(this.root.w); // attempt to keep square-ish by growing down  when width  is much greater than height
    var shouldGrowRight = canGrowRight && Decimal.add(this.root.w, w).lessThanOrEqualTo(this.root.h); // attempt to keep square-ish by growing right when height is much greater than width
    
    if(shouldGrowRight) {
        return this.growRight(w, h);
    }
    else if(shouldGrowDown) {
        return this.growDown(w, h);
    }
    else if(canGrowRight) {
        return this.growRight(w, h);
    }
    else if(canGrowDown) {
        return this.growDown(w, h);
    }
    else{
        return this.growDown(w, h); // need to ensure sensible root starting size to avoid this happening
    }
  },

  growRight: function(w, h) {
    this.root = {
      used: true,
      x: setFloat(0),
      y: setFloat(0),
      w: Decimal.add(this.root.w, w),
      h: this.root.h,
      down: this.root,
      right: { x: this.root.w, y: 0, w: w, h: this.root.h }
    };
    var node;
    if (node = this.findNode(this.root, w, h))
      return this.splitNode(node, w, h);
    else
      return null;
  },

  growDown: function(w, h) {
    this.root = {
      used: true,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: this.root.w,
      h: Decimal.add(this.root.h, h),
      down:  { x: 0, y: this.root.h, w: this.root.w, h: h },
      right: this.root
    };
    var node;
    if (node = this.findNode(this.root, w, h))
      return this.splitNode(node, w, h);
    else
      return null;
  }

}

class Line {
    strokeStyle = '#ddd';
    
    constructor(fX, fY, tX, tY) {
        this.fX = fX;
        this.fY = fY;
        this.tX = tX;
        this.tY = tY;
    }
    
    get length() {
        const hL = Math.pow(this.tX - this.fX, 2);
        const vL = Math.pow(this.tY - this.fY, 2);
        const l = Math.sqrt(hL + vL);
        return l;
    }
    
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.fX, this.fY);
        ctx.lineTo(this.tX, this.tY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

[image: Preview of the issue]

In this case the boxes from the right side should be aligned to the bottom of the blue square to reduce the size of the blue square.

Could you help me out, to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Review Code style & structure

I am not going to give a better solution (there are plenty of solutions available online [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)) See Bin Packing under rewrite for some hints.

This is code review so I will review your code.

#### Low level language style?

I get the strong feeling that this code has been lifted from a lower level (language) example.

Why do I think so? because lower level languages are often strongly typed and can require functions to do basic operations like `add`, `sub`, `isLessThan`, etc..

When using example from other languages avoid coping type based code as these can have a serious performance penalty in JS

Functions of concern

```
 a.lessThanOrEqualTo(b) // replaced with a <= b
 Decimal.add(a, b)      // replaced with a + b
 Decimal.sub(a, b)      // replaced with a - b *??
 setFloat(a)            // replaced with a
```

`*` You have not included some important information. `Decimal.sub(a, b)` does not indicate its direction. Is it `a - b` or `b - a` ???

#### General style

- A returning statement should not be followed by an `else` statement. eg `if (foo) { return } else { boo = foo }` should be `if (foo) { return } boo = foo;`
- Idiomatic JS has the `else` on the same line as the closing `}`
- Always delimit all code blocks. eg `if (foo) return` should be `if (foo) { return }`
- Use [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) when variables are constants.
- Use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) rather then [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) when possible
- Avoid assignments inside statement clauses. `if (foo = boo()) {` should be `foo = boo(); if (foo) {`
- Avoid `null` and use the default `undefined` Null does not mean undefined, `null`'s semantic meaning has been lost in JS but can generally be considered a place holder, though `undefined` can also be used as such.
- Avoid accessing global's by passing data to functions.

  Doing so makes the code independent of the scope it exists in, making code more portable.

  For example the function `growNode` is accessing a higher level scope via `limit` and `form`. These objects should be passed to the function, better yet only the values of interest should be passed to the function. See rewrite function `growNode`

#### Use modern JS syntax.

- Object property function short cut [Functions.Method_definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) when declaring functions for objects. eg `fit: function(blocks) {` should be `fit(blocks) {`
- Object property short cut when possible. `{x: x, y: y}` should be `{x, y}`
- Use the [** (Exponentiation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation)  operator rather than [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow), [Math.sqrt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt), or [Math.cbrt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cbrt)

  On the subject of powers the very common operation of a "line segment length" can be performed using [Math.hypot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) however `Math.hypot` is considerably slower than manually calculating the length of a known dimensioned line segment (Most likely because `hypot` is multi dimensional) .

  From experiment I have found that the quickest way to compute the length of a line segment in JS is as follows

  ```
  const dx = x1 - x2, dy = y1 - y2;
  const length = (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
  ```

  Note that in many cases you can avoid the root operation is you need only the relative lengths

  ```
  const dx = x1 - x2, dy = y1 - y2;
  const lengthSqr = dx * dx + dy * dy;
  ```

### Rewrite

The rewrite covers most of the review points with some additions.

- Added Node and NodeEx (Ex for extended) to reduce the code footprint needed to create Nodes.
- Slight modifications to the line

  - Uses a static property for line style
  - Changed the way length is calculated
  - Just to highlight the after `ctx.beginPath` the first call to `ctx.moveTo` is identical to `ctx.lineTo` .

**NOTE:** The rewrite is an example ONLY! It is untested apart from being parsed. Without any tests I can not offer any guarantee that the code actually works.

```
const Node = (x, y, w, h) => ({x, y, w, h});
const NodeEx = (x, y, w, h, used = false, down, right) => ({x, y, w, h, used, down, right});

const GrowingPacker = function() { };
GrowingPacker.prototype = {
    fit(blocks) {
        this.root = Node(0, 0, ...(blocks.length ? [blocks[0].w, blocks[0].h] : [0, 0]));
        for (const block of blocks) {
            const node = node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h);
            block.fit = node ?
                this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h) :
                this.growNode(block.w, block.h);
        }
    },
    findNode(root, w, h) {
        return root.used ?
            this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h) :
            (w < root.w && h <root.h ? root : undefined); 
    },
    splitNode(node, w, h) {
        node.used = true;
        node.down = Node(node.x,  node.y + h, node.w, node.h - h);
        node.right = Node(node.x + w, node.y, node.w - w, h);
        return node;
    },     
    growNode: function(w, h, maxW, maxH) { // maxWidth and maxHeight passed as maxW and maxH
        const [grownW, grownH] = [this.root.w + w, this.root.h + h];
        const down  = grownH <= maxH && w <= this.root.w;
        const right = grownW <= maxW && h <= this.root.h;
        
        if (right && grownW <= this.root.h) { return this.growRight(w, h) }
        if (down && grownH <= this.root.w) { return this.growDown(w, h) }
        if (right) { return this.growRight(w, h) }
        if (down) { return this.growDown(w, h) }
        return this.growDown(w, h); 
    },
    grown(w, h) {
        const node = this.findNode(this.root, w, h);
        if (node) { return this.splitNode(node, w, h) }
    },
    growRight(w, h) {
        this.root = NodeEx(
            0, 0, this.root.w + w, this.root.h, 
            true, this.root, Node(this.root.w, 0, w, this.root.h)
        );
        return grown(w, h);
    },
    growDown(w, h) {
        this.root = NodeEx(
            0, 0, this.root.w , this.root.h + h, 
            true, Node(0, this.root.h, 0, this.root.w, h), this.root
        );        
        return grown(w, h);
    },
}

class Line {
    static strokeStyle = "#ddd";
    constructor(fX, fY, tX, tY, style = Line.strokeStyle) {
        this.fX = fX;
        this.fY = fY;
        this.tX = tX;
        this.tY = tY;
        this.style = style;
    }    
    get length() {
        const hL = this.tX - this.fX, vL = this.tY - this.fY;
        return (hL * hL + vL * vL) ** 0.5;
    }
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = style;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(this.fX, this.fY);
        ctx.lineTo(this.tX, this.tY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

### Bin Packing

Your question.

> *"Bin-packing-problem - is there a way to do it better?"*

Very likely, but how much better depends on what you are packing into the bin and the nature of the bin.

The image shows that there are many options for a better solution. (boxes separated by 1 px)

[image: Numbers indicate the bin size]

<sub>Numbers indicate the bin size</sub>

Problem solving starts with the human approach

When we humans pack stuff we have the ability to see all the stuff to pack in one glance and as such can formulate a strategy before we start to pack the bins.

Generally the task is to fit items. If we pack and it turns out that it wont fit, we rearrange the packing by removing items and trying a different arrangement.

Or we change the bin and start again.

These are all strategies you can use to address the packing problem.

- Evaluate the objects to be packed.
- Can sub groups be packed highly efficiently. Group them to be packed as a group.
- Compare different combinations of placements.
- Change the bin constraints and start again.

You say

> *`But in some cases boxes do not organize well.`*

Aesthetics is not a concern unless you are packing a display, however a well pack bin does have a tendency to be aesthetically pleasing.